# Is this the right understanding of SOLID Object Oriented principles?

Tags: oop

After reading about [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) in a few places, I was having trouble mapping between explanations with different vocabularies and code. To generalize a bit, I created the diagrams below, and I was hoping that people could point out any 'bugs' in my understanding.

Of course, feel free to reuse/remix/redistribute as you'd like!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your diagrams look quite nice, but I'm afraid that I couldn't understand them (particularly the interface one), so I'll comment on the text.

It's not really clear to me what you mean by layer, in the Open/closed I thought you might mean interface, but the interface and dependency items suggest you don't mean that.

Open/closed : actually your text from the Liskov item is closer to describing open/closed. If the code is open for extension, we can make use of it (by extending it) to implement new requirements, but by not modifying the existing code (it's closed for modification) we know we wont break any existing code that made use of it.

"Only depend on outer layer" - if this means only depend on an interface not the implementation, then yes, that's an important principle for SOLID code even though it doesn't map directly to any of the 5 letters.

Dependency inversion uses that but goes beyond it. A piece of code can make use of another via its interface and this is has great maintainability benefits over relying on the implementation, but if the calling code still has the responsibility for creating the object (and therefore choosing the class) that implements the interface then it still has a dependency. If we create the concrete object outside the class or method and pass it in as an interface, then the called code no longer depends on the concrete class, just the interface

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    IThing myIthing* = new ConcreteThing();
    // code below can use the interface but this function depends on the Concrete class          
}

void SomeFunctionDependencyInjectedVersion(IThing myIthing*)
{
     // this version should be able to work with any class that implements the IThing interface,
    // whether it really can might depend on some of the other SOLID principles
}
```

Single responsibility : this isn't about classes intersecting, this is about not giving a code more than one responsibility. If you have a function where you can't think of a better name than doSomethingAndSomethingElse this might be a sign its got more than one responsibility and could be better if it was split (the point I'm making is about the "and" in the name even when the "somethings" are better named).
You should try to define that responsibility so that the class can perform it entirely, (although it make may use of other classes that perform sub-responsibilities for it) but at each level of responsibility that a class is defined it should have one clear reason to exist. When it has more than one it can make code harder to understand, and changes to code related to one responsibility can have unwanted side-effects on other responsibilities.

Iterface segregation: Consider a class implementing a collection. The class will implement code to add to the collection or to read from it. We could put all this in one interface, but if we separate it then when we have consuming code that only needs to read and doesn't need to add to the collection then it can use the interface made of the reading methods. This can make the code clearer in that it shows quickly that the code only needs those methods, and, if we've injected the collection by interface we could also use that code with a different source of items that doesn't have the ability to add items
(consider IEnumerable vs ICollection vs IList)

Liskov substitution is all about making sure that objects that inherit from an interface/base class behave in the way that the interface/base class promised to behave. In the strictest interpretation of the original definition they'd need to behave exactly the same, but that's not all that useful. More generally its about behaving in a consistent and expected way, the derived classes may add functionality, but they should be able to do the job of the base objects (they can be substituted for them)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Now that I've got the a better angle on the concepts, I'll look back at my Python specific resources and try to get them to make sense.